# .Net Core - MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to make the Create method the Estoque entity, but when trying to register I get an error.

Error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`rkmes`.`estoque`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_Estoque_Linha_LinhaId` FOREIGN KEY (`LinhaId`) REFERENCES `linha`
>   (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
>   MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.TryAsyncContinuation(Task>
>   task) in ServerSession.cs, line 1169
>
> MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`rkmes`.`estoque`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_Estoque_Linha_LinhaId` FOREIGN KEY (`LinhaId`) REFERENCES `linha`
>   (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(ResultSet
>   resultSet) in MySqlDataReader.cs, line 93
>
> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See
>   the inner exception for details.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

these are my methods:

Class **EstoqueService**

```
public async Task InsertAsync(Estoque obj)
        {
            _context.Estoque.Add(obj);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

**EstoqueController**

```
//GET CREATE
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            var linha = await _linhaContext.FindAllAsync();
            var tipoEstoque = await _tipoEstoqueContext.FindAllAsync();
            var viewModel = new EstoqueViewModel
            {
                Linhas = linha,
                TipoEstoques = tipoEstoque
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        //POST CREATE
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Estoque obj)
        {
            /*verifica se post é valido. Se  o js estiver desabilitado no navegador do usuario
            ele consegue dar post vazio, esse if serve para previnir isso*/
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var linha = await _linhaContext.FindAllAsync();
                var tipoEstoque = await _tipoEstoqueContext.FindAllAsync();
                var viewModel = new EstoqueViewModel
                {
                    Linhas = linha,
                    TipoEstoques = tipoEstoque
                };
                return View(viewModel);
            }
            await _estoqueContext.InsertAsync(obj);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

Class **EstoqueViewModel**

```
public class EstoqueViewModel
    {
        public Estoque estoque { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Linha> Linhas { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TipoEstoque> TipoEstoques { get; set; }
    }
```

View **create**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="estoque.Nome" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="estoque.Nome" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="estoque.Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="estoque.Descricao" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="estoque.Descricao" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="estoque.Descricao" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="estoque.TipoEstoqueId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="estoque.TipoEstoqueId" class ="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.TipoEstoques,"Id","Nome"))"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="estoque.LinhaId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="estoque.LinhaId" class ="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Linhas,"Id","Nome","Descricao"))"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the Estoque record, you must have two select of the Linha and TupoEstoque entities.

I am using the MYSQL provider.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

*There are topics on this site that have already been discussed about this error, but none helped me resolve it.*

Comment: What is the defination for `Estoque`? Share us the code for the three models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current design, I assume value for `Estoque obj` will be null. This is caused by that when you submit form with your current view, it will submit data like

```
estoque.Name: sfe
estoque.TipoEstoqueId: 3
estoque.LinhaId: 2
```

This will fail to bind data to `Estoque obj`.

For a workaround, follow ways below:

1. `Model`

   ```
   public class Estoque
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public int LinhaId { get; set; }
       public virtual Linha Linha { get; set; }
       public int TipoEstoqueId { get; set; }
       public virtual TipoEstoque TipoEstoque { get; set; }

   }
   public class Linha
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string LName { get; set; }
   }
   public class TipoEstoque
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string TName { get; set; }
   }
   public class EstoqueViewModel
   {
       public Estoque estoque { get; set; }
       public ICollection<Linha> Linhas { get; set; }
       public ICollection<TipoEstoque> TipoEstoques { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Controller

   ```
   public class EstoqueController : Controller
   {
       private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
       public EstoqueController(ApplicationDbContext context)
       {
           _context = context;
       }
       public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
       {
           var linha = await _context.Linha.ToListAsync();
           var tipoEstoque = await _context.TipoEstoque.ToListAsync();
           var viewModel = new EstoqueViewModel
           {
               estoque = new Estoque(),
               Linhas = linha,
               TipoEstoques = tipoEstoque
           };
           return View(viewModel);
       }
       //POST CREATE
       [HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EstoqueViewModel obj)
       {
           /*verifica se post é valido. Se  o js estiver desabilitado no navegador do usuario
           ele consegue dar post vazio, esse if serve para previnir isso*/
           if (!ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               var linha = await _context.Linha.ToListAsync();
               var tipoEstoque = await _context.TipoEstoque.ToListAsync();
               var viewModel = new EstoqueViewModel
               {
                   estoque = new Estoque(),
                   Linhas = linha,
                   TipoEstoques = tipoEstoque
               };
               return View(viewModel);
           }
           var model = obj.estoque;

           await _context.Estoque.AddAsync(model);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           return Ok("OK");
       }
   }
   ```
3. View

   ```
   @model EstoqueViewModel
   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
       //var estoque = new Estoque();
   }

   <h1>Create</h1>

   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
           <form asp-action="Create">
               <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="@Model.estoque.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                   <input asp-for="@Model.estoque.Name" class="form-control" />
                   <span asp-validation-for="@Model.estoque.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="@Model.estoque.TipoEstoqueId" class="control-label"></label>
                   <select asp-for="@Model.estoque.TipoEstoqueId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.TipoEstoques,"Id","TName"))"></select>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label asp-for="@Model.estoque.LinhaId" class="control-label"></label>
                   <select asp-for="@Model.estoque.LinhaId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Linhas,"Id","LName"))"></select>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: I tested your solution here and it worked, but before I can give you an answer, I'd like to know if it's possible to explain to me better your answer, your code. could you explain me?

Comment: @Renan Your issue is caused by model binding, for post send request with `estoque.Name: sfe`, but your server side expected `Name` for bind.